# How to know which object roboearth is seeing

Tags: ros, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm new with roboearth. I've already created some models in my computer and I have also succeded when trying to detect the object. The problem is: when I load different models and I put the detector to work, is there any way to know which object is being detected? I mean, is there a service/node/something that says "I've detected a box", "I've detected a can", etc. ?

Any help is welcome! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52172/how-to-know-which-object-roboearth-is-seeing/) by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recognized objects should be published on the re_kinect/detection_results topic, see also here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/re_kinect_object_detector?distro=fuerte

You should be able to see them by calling the following command in a terminal:
rostopic echo /re_kinect/detection_results

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2013-02-04**:
thanks moritz!